# Creating a new stack operation

Tags: java, time, stack

I'm doing a practice stack problem that deals with 2 stacks. Stack S and stack T and it wants us to basically make a new operation called bottom that returns but does not delete the bottom element of s. So my breakdown of the problem and how to go about doing this was to first fill stack S with elements. Next would be to fill stack T with all of stack S' elements but in reverse order so that now the bottom is on the top. My question though is that I know how to create the initial stack S but I do not know how to fill stack T in reverse order. Also, what would be the running time since it would be in reverse?

Comment: the first thing I did was to google `java stack` - what have you done?

Answer (score 2):

If you repeatedly pop elements off of stack S and push them onto stack T as you are popping, then when S is empty, T will contain what used to be in S, but in reverse order.

```
  S      T

| 1 |  -----
| 2 |
| 3 |
-----
```

`T.push(S.pop())` =>

```
  S      T

| 2 |  | 1 |
| 3 |  -----
-----
```

`T.push(S.pop())` =>

```
  S      T

| 3 |  | 2 |
-----  | 1 |
       -----
```

`T.push(S.pop())` =>

```
  S      T

-----  | 3 |
       | 2 |
       | 1 |
       -----
```

The running time will be linear in the number of elements in S.

Comment: Thank you! That little excerpt of code really helped out because I was stuck on how to literally go about how to pop each element from stack S over to T and now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Stack S and stack T and it wants us to basically make a new operation
>   called bottom that returns but does not delete the bottom element of s

I do not see how that can be done directly without violating the basics of `Stack` operation. The only thing you are supposed to let the user have a look at , with out without deleting , is the element at the top of the stack.

If you want to let user see the what is at the bottom, you will need another stack where you **push all the popped elements from S**. Then, whatever is at the top of this new stack is whatever was at the bottom of stack `S`.

**Now, that seems to lead to your second issue, doesn't it ?**

So, consider this possible solution:
1. You will have a method called `int pushInto(Stack S,Stack T)`
2. When the user wants to see the bottom element of the stack S, call this method.
3. This method will then return the element what is at the top of the Stack T i.e. the bottom of S.
4. This method needs to be used in conjunction with the method: `int getBottomElement(Stack S)`
*I am trying to hit two birds in one stone*